# shimano fc4400 double chainring replacement

Tags: shimano, chainring, compatibility

I am looking to replace my Tiagra fc4400 52t chainring, however it seems to be out of stock everywhere.

Based on the parameters (130BCD, 52t) I found a few alternatives, however all of them are 10 speed.

Also, I am not sure I can put them on the same 4400 crank, as it seems the new chainset's connecting sides are slightly wider. Would it simply be a visual mismatch, or can I expect any installing/usage problems?

[image: 4400 chainring]

[image: 5700 chainring]

If the 5700 chainring is not usable on this chainset, is there another you could recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: As long as the BCD is the same, you should be right.  Changing number of teeth may upset the FD, so stay with 52.  And make sure you mount the chainring the right way around (probably logos facing out.)

Comment: thanks for the reply! I found on a few blogs that the internal width of 10 speed chains is the same as 9 speed - which makes me feel safer buying newer chainrings.

regarding 52 vs 50 teeth on the ring - would it be not just a matter of lowering the FD slightly? or can there be more issues? as I've seen shimano sells a few types of double type B chainsets - 52/39 and 50/39 doubles are popular, and I have actually thought to reduce it to 50 (as I am a "fresh cyclist" my legs would rather work on the cadence rather than more force :)

Answer (score 1):

BCD is the key, Shimano 9 and 10 speed chainrings are interchangable. Dropping a couple of teeth is not a problem, just adjust the front derailleur and check the chain length. Really focus on the BCD, as Shimano road has standard and compact chainsets and they can both take 50 tooth chainrings. You probably have a 130 BCD, if you are running the usual 52/39, the 110 BCD compact chainsets are usually 50/34.